# How to search and delete all line having "xyx" as substring recursively, only from dir1 dir2 dir3 .. dirN

Tags: bash, replace, sed, find, alias

Im trying to figure out following,

> 1) How to search and delete all line having "xyx" as substring
>   recursively, only from dir1 dir2 dir3 .. dirN I have tried something
>   like but not worked,

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type f -exec sed -r -i "/xyz/d" {} +
```

OR

```
find . -path dir1 -path dir2 -path dir3 -type f -exec sed -r -i "/xyz/d" {} +
```

> 2) How to write alias for above command in bashrc after getting
>   answer of above, something like similar to following

```
myfunction() {
    find $1 ... -type f -exec sed -r -i "/xyz/d" {} +
OR  
    find $1 $2 $k -type f -exec sed -r -i "/xyz/d" {} +
OR  
    find $1 -type f -exec sed -r -i "/$2/d" {} +
}
alias foo=myfunction
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: what do you mean does not work

Comment: @Azad means command getting executed but not deleting lines with substring xyz. but If i pass only one dir then its works fine "find dir1 -type f -exec sed -r -i "/xyz/d" {} + ". I want to know ho I can search specific multiple directories.

Comment: @ypp it worked for me (with two dir). there's a small chance it might be related to your bash or version